# Is the unit ball compact on $C([0,1])$ with $||.||_1$?

Tags: real-analysis

If I define a sequence $f_n$ on $(0,1)$ so that is a triangle of high 1 in $(0,1/n)$ and null in $(1/n,1)$ can i say the unit ball isn't compact?

Comment: The unit ball of what metric space?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $f_n$ to be triangular over $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ with height $2n(n+1),$ $f_n=0$ elsewhere. What is $\|f_n-f_m\|_1$ if $m\ne n?$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(t)-f_m(t)| dt=\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(t)| dt + \int_{0}^{1} |f_m(t)| dt$=2

Comment: so there isn't convergence?